# Getting Control-slash to work in emacs in ConEmu

Tags: emacs, conemu

I can't figure out how to have ConEmu send Control-slash (C-/) to emacs -nw (i.e. the plain terminal emacs, no X / GUI).  This is the simplest keyboard shortcut for "undo" in emacs - very handy.  It seems emacs doesn't receive this keystroke at all, since C-h k (describe key) C-/ acts as if I didn't press anything.  The same problem happens whether I run emacs directly as a new ConEmu console, or start it from a cmd / bash Conemu console.

Comment: Strange - works for me.  What emacs are you running?

Comment: Windows 7, ConEmu alpha build from 170705.  Emacs is 25.2.  I've tried starting a cygwin bash session, then using its emacs -nw, and also from a DOS session using GNU's native emacs.exe -nw.  Both work fine except C-/ isn't even sent to emacs: C-h k C-/ doesn't do anything.

I should say my real interest isn't in running emacs locally from conemu - I just run the full windows GUI version.  But, I ssh into remote machines and for speed would rather do emacs -nw than open Xwindows.

C-_ still works, I will live, but C-/ would be nice.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 also, and find that C-/ works fine when:
(1) start (Cygwin) emacs -nw from a regular Cygwin64 terminal (i.e. minnty running bash);
(2) start native emacs from either cmd.exe or a plain (i.e., not running a shell) conemu.
*If*, however, I start a Cygwin bash shell under ConEmu, I see the same
results as you.  (If I start a MinGW bash shell under ConEmu, it works
properly using native emacs.)
I would suggest using another key-binding for undo.  (I like M-z, for example - (global-set-key (kbd "M-z") 'undo).)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried ssh'ing to a remote machine (using Cygwin ssh), and also had no trouble with C-/.  (The remote machine runs FreeBSD and the shell is (t)csh.

Comment: Thanks very much for investigating.  Seems like cygwin bash in ConEmu, then emacs -nw is a weird corner case.  I'll follow one of your suggestions.

Comment: Did you try to update ConEmu to latest preview?

Comment: I just tried preview 170807, still no luck.  Meaning, running emacs -nw, C-/ doesn't undo, and C-h k (describe keystroke) doesn't recognize C-/.  Any more thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think the comments by varro provide enough of an answer.  ConEmu + cygwin bash + emacs -nw doesn't work, but other combinations do.